# Social icons not aligning next to each other - css/html

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align these social media icons next to each other but it's not working.  I thought the inline block would solve this issue but it hasn't. What am I missing or doing wrong?

[image]

```css
.social-buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.social-icon {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 138px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 138px;
  border-radius: 138px;
  border: 5px solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.social-icon-no-border {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 138px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 138px;
  border-radius: 138px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.social-icon:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
}

.social-icon-no-border:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
}


/* Facebook Button Styling */

.facebook {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  border-color: #3b5998;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.twitter {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-color: #55acee;
  background-color: #55acee;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.linkedin {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  background-color: #0976b4;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #0976b4;
}

.youtube {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  background-color: #bb0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #bb0000;
}

.instagram {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-buttons">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon facebook">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://linkedin.com/" class="social-margin" target="blank">
    <div class="social-icon linkedin">
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://instagram.com/" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon-no-border instagram">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://twitter.com/" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon twitter">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://youtube.com/" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon youtube">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: which browser are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted in your question does, in fact, align horizontally. However, you might find flexbox to be a more useful alignment tool.

The reason `inline-block` sometimes doesn't work is because `inline-block` works on the element itself - but you want it to work on the parent container (div `social-buttons`). Instead, use flexbox:

```css
.social-buttons {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* flex vertical alignment */
  justify-content: space-evenly; /* flex horiz alignment - center is better */
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.social-margin{
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.social-icon {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 138px;
  border: 5px solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 1px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.social-icon-no-border {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 138px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.social-icon:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
}

.social-icon-no-border:hover {
  transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
}


/* Facebook Button Styling */

.facebook {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  border-color: #3b5998;
  background-color: #3b5998;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.twitter {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-color: #55acee;
  background-color: #55acee;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.linkedin {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  background-color: #0976b4;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #0976b4;
}

.youtube {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  background-color: #bb0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #bb0000;
}

.instagram {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-buttons">
  <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon facebook">
      <i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://linkedin.com/" class="social-margin" target="blank">
    <div class="social-icon linkedin">
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://instagram.com/" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon-no-border instagram">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://twitter.com/" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon twitter">
      <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a href="http://youtube.com/" target="blank" class="social-margin">
    <div class="social-icon youtube">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Here is a brilliant, fast-paced [video tutorial on using flexbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k32voqQhODc):

And here is my [fav cheatsheet](https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/):

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this:

```
.social-buttons {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give display flex to the parent of the box and increase the width of the box.

```
.icons{
     display:flex;
     width: (increase the width)px;
}
```